# gradle Annotation processor 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor' not found

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, annotation-processor

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl"
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot"
compile "org.springframework:spring-webflux"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb"
compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-core"
compile group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-jdk8', version: '1.4.1.Final'
apt "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.1.Final"

annotationProcessor(
        "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.4.0",
        "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16"
     )
 .............
   }

querydsl {
   
    springDataMongo = true
    querydslSourcesDir = file("${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/querydsl")
}
```

**What went wrong:**
Execution failed for task ':event-sourcing:compileQuerydsl'.

> Annotation processor 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor' not found

How to fix it?

How can we write custom plugin for MongoAnnotationProcessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same issue and please update or reduce the version of spring-data-mongodb